# trasform hex to hexcodepoint

Tags: python, hex, encode, utf

I have a hex code like this:

```
\xf0\x9f\x94\xb4
```

And I want to encode this like this:

```
1F534
```

How can I transform it with a method in python 2.7?

Thanks

Comment: It is not encoding it is utf-8 decoding... >>> t= "\xf0\x9f\x94\xb4"
>>> ut = t.decode('utf8')
>>> hex(ord(ut)) . Only posted as a comment because the current question is unclear and contains no Python code.
'0x1f534'

Comment: Tomorrow I'll try it and if it works, you should post a answer. Thanks!

Comment: @SergeBallesta I can't follow your steps, Whe I execute ut = t.decode("utf8") and late hex(ord(ut)) I get this error: TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

Comment: Show your code.  I cannot guess what `t` is.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have not code, I'm executing commands in shell. t = "\xf0\x9f\x94\xb4" like you commented.

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I use 2.7

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Python 2.7.13. What gives `print [hex(ord(i)) for i in ut]`

Comment: @SergeBallesta ['0xd83d', '0xdd34'] ¿Do you want to chat?

Comment: Oups! It is worse than what I had imagined. Python can be compiler to internally process unicode as UCS-2 (2bytes) or UCS-4 (4 bytes). Mine is UCS-4 while yours is UCS-2. I have to do more tests...

Comment: @SergeBallesta ok, thansk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are just asking: how can I find the unicode code of the character represented in utf8 with the (byte) string `'\xf0\x9f\x94\xb4'`?

In Python3 it would be as simple as:

```
>>> hex(ord(b'\xf0\x9f\x94\xb4'.decode()))
'0x1f534'
```

In a Python2 version compiled with --enable-unicode=ucs4, it would be more or less the same:

```
>>> hex(ord('\xf0\x9f\x94\xb4'.decode('utf-8')))
'0x1f534'
```

But after your comments, you have a Python 2.7 version compiled with --enable-unicode=ucs2. In that case, Unicode strings actually contain a UTF16 representation of the string:

```
>>> print [hex(ord(i)) for i in '\xf0\x9f\x94\xb4'.decode('utf-8')]
['0xd83d', '0xdd34']
```

with no direct way to find the true unicode code point of the U+1F534 LARGE RED CIRCLE character.

The last option is then to decode the utf8 sequence *by hand*. You can find the description of the UTF8 encoding on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). The following function take an utf-8 representation of an unicode character and return its code point:

```
def from_utf8(bstr):
    b = [ord(i) for i in bstr]
    if b[0] & 0x80 == 0: return b
    if b[0] & 0xe0 == 0xc0:
        return ((b[0] & 0x1F) << 6) | (b[1] & 0x3F)
    if b[0] & 0xf0 == 0xe0:
        return ((b[0] & 0xF) << 12) | ((b[1] & 0x3F) << 6) | (b[2] & 0x3F)
    else:
        return ((b[0] & 7) << 18) | ((b[1] & 0x3F) << 12) | \
               ((b[2] & 0x3F) << 6) | (b[3] & 0x3F)
```

Beware, no control is done here to make sure that the string is a correct UTF-8 representation of a single character... But at least it gives the expected result:

```
>>> print hex(from_utf8("\xf0\x9f\x94\xb4"))
0x1f534
```